# Issue in using pagination in R3 Corda

Tags: corda

We are querying the vault and fetching the records which are more than 200 per nodes but getting the following error -
Please specify a `PageSpecification` as there are more results [201] than the default page size [200]
After increasing the pagination to 400 from the default 200, I am getting java heap out of memory error.
Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the heap size available to the node by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/running-a-node.html#starting-an-individual-corda-node.

If you continue to get an out-of-memory exception, you should either increase the memory allocated to the Java process further, or inspect your node's database to see if the transaction objects are abnormally large.

Comment: It is still not working and when I am trying to fetch many records from h2 db tables then I am getting the following error - org.h2.message.DbException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Last block not stored, possibly due to out-of-memory [1.4.194/3]" [50000-194]. Can you please let me know what I can do?

Comment: That's the expected error. It sounds like the transaction objects may be too large, even for the larger memory footprint. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375958/buffer-overflow-issue-when-rows-in-vault-is-more-than-200.

Answer (score 0):

you can always add pagination logic for fetching the large number of records. please find the this link :
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-vault-query.html