# H2 DB persistence.mv.db file size increases even on data cleanup in CordApp

Tags: corda

Persistence.mv.db size increases even on wiping out old data. And after size increases more than 71 Mb it gives handshake timeout(netty connection). Nodes stop responding to REST services.
We have cleared data from tables like NODE_MESSAGE_IDS, NODE_OUR_KEY_PAIRS, due to large number of hoping between six nodes. And generation of temporary key pairs for a session. And similarly many other tables, e.g. node_transactions, even after clearing them, size increases.
And also when we declare:
val session = serviceHub.jdbcSession()
"session.autoCommit is false" everytime. Also I tries to set its value to true, and execute sql queries.But it did not decrease database size.

This is in reference to the same project. We solved pagination issue by removing the data from tables but DB size still increases. So it is not completely solved:-
[Buffer overflow issue when rows in vault is more than 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375958/buffer-overflow-issue-when-rows-in-vault-is-more-than-200)

Comment: How are you wiping out the old data?

Comment: val session = serviceHub.jdbcSession()

val deleteQuery ="delete from NODE_MESSAGE_IDS"

session.preparedStatement(deleteQuery).execute()

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? You should be able to extract it from the node logs (each node creates a log in `./logs`).

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with your flows, as the node is doing a lot of checkpointing.

Besides that I cannot think of any other scenarios to cause the database to constantly growing.